# Scene doesn't fully show after changing from another scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my MenuScene I have a play Button and if I touch it, it changes to the GameScene using this code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if atPoint(location).name == "playButton" {
            let playScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            let playSceneTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            playScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(playScene, transition: playSceneTransition)

            }
    }
```

But the GameScene looks like it's in the bottom left corner and only shows the top right corner of the Scene. If I change the GameViewCotroller to show the GameScene instead of the MenuScene when I start the game it's looks perfectly fine. why is that? is there something wrong with the code to go to the GameScene?

Comment: May have something to do with your GameScene anchor point property, do you modify it?

Comment: No i never changed anything of the anchor point property.

Comment: The two things I notice here is that it looks like the problem is (obviously) coming from your GameScene class (since displaying an other scene isn't an issue), and this looks pretty similar to an issue you would encounter when adding a SKSpriteNode at (0,0) with anchor point (0.5, 0.5). What are your GameScene children?

Comment: Oh wait, I just noticed that my GameScene.sks and .swift files are't linked anymore for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "linked"?

Comment: In my .sks the background is blue but when i launch the game the background is white, and also if add a Sprite in the .sks i don't see it in the game.

Comment: Is your GameScene.sks file still pointing to your GameScene class (in the "Custom class inspector")?

Comment: Yes it is, and in the attributes inspector it's also the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are loading your MenuScene via an SKS file.  This by default puts your anchor point at 0.5,0.5.

You are then transitioning to game scene using a size initializer, not an SKS file, with `GameScene(size: self.size)`, which is going to have an anchor point of 0,0 or 0.5,0.5 depending on what version of iOS your users are loading up.

I would recommend avoiding using `GameScene(size: self.size)` and use `GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")` to keep yourself consistent.